# PS 5.1 Workflow MaxSessionsPerWorkflow

Tags: powershell, workflow

How can I increase the sessions in a PS 5.1 Workflow?
I've tried setting the max to 10 using this

```
$wfopt = New-PSWorkflowExecutionOption -MaxSessionsPerWorkflow 10 -MaxDisconnectedSessions 200
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name wfname -SessionTypeOption $wfopt -Force
```

I then reference the session configuration in the command like this

```
Run-MyCommand -PSConfigurationName wfname -Servers $Workload
```

But the WorkFlow is still limited to 5 sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone down the RunSpace route instead.This article was great guidance: https://xkln.net/blog/multithreading-in-powershell--running-a-specific-number-of-threads/